# CTE Recursive Query to Grandparents

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery, recursive-query

I have following table:

```
ID NAME PARENT_ID ISDELETED ISINEDIT
1  JJ     NULL     1          0
2  AR     1        0          0
3 PR      2        0          0
4 DR      NULL     0          1
```

What I need to get is SELECT query that will return only rows that have ISDELETED 0 and ISINEDIT 0 and whose parents or grandparents are 0 as well

I currently have:

```
;WITH ChildParent AS
(
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.name,
        a.isinedit,
        a.parent_id,
        a.isdeleted
    FROM dbo.table 
    WHERE isdeleted = 0 AND isinedit = 0 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.name,
        a.isinedit,
        a.parent_id,
        a.isdeleted
    FROM dbo.table a
    INNER JOIN ChildParent cp ON a.parent_id = cp.id
    WHERE a.isdeleted = 0  AND a.isinedit = 0
)
SELECT  
        id,
        name,
    parent_id,
        isinedit,
        isdeleted
FROM ChildParent
```

But for some reason it returns double rows

Comment: I recommend creating a `VIEW` that only shows valid records, and defining the CTE over that `VIEW` rather than the base-table. You could also use a prior CTE with the same filter criteria btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the same `isdeleted = 0 AND isinedit = 0` predicate to the `INNER JOIN childParent CP` source.

...but if you do that you make your CTE query very fiddly and if you have to repeat the same thing over-and-over there's probably a better way to do it.

...and there is! A `SELECT` query can have multiple CTE expressions:

```
;
WITH filtered AS
(
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.name,
        a.parent_id,
    FROM
        dbo.Table
    WHERE
        IsDeleted = 0
        AND
        IsInEdit = 0 
)

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.name,
        a.parent_id
    FROM
        filtered

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.name,
        a.parent_id
    FROM
        filtered
        INNER JOIN cte ON a.parent_id = cte.id
)
SELECT  
    *
FROM
    cte
ORDER BY
    id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is bit more complicated than you think. As I understand your question, you need to traverse the whole parent hierarchy of each node first, and *then* check if any parent does not fulfill the rules (you can optimize it a little by stopping *after* the first non-compliant parent is met).

You also need to keep track of the original node, so you can properly filter in the outer query (which avoids the duplicates that you are currently getting).

I would phrase your query as:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        t.*, 
        t.id original_id, 
        0 lvl, 
        1 is_ok
    from dbo.table t
    where isdeleted = 0 and isinedit = 0 
    union all
    select 
        t.*, 
        c.original_id, 
        c.lvl + 1, 
        case when t.isdeleted = 0 and t.isinedit = 0 then 1 else 0 end
    from dbo.table t
    inner join cte c on c.parent_id = t.id
    where c.is_ok = 1
)
select *
from cte c
where 
    c.lvl = 0
    and not exists (
        select 1 from cte c1 where c1.original_id = c.original_id and c1.is_ok = 0
    )
```

Note that this query will work regardless of how many levels exists in the tree (if you have more than 100 levels, you need to add `option(maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

These type of queries are easier if you create a clean data set first in a CTE.  It gets rid of the extra filtering clauses in all of the CTE queries.

In this case, return all rows not deleted and not in is edit.   Next would be getting your data Grand Parent INNER JOIN Parent INNER JOIN CHILD

```
;WITH GoodDataRows AS
(
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.name,
        a.isinedit,
        a.parent_id,
        a.isdeleted
    FROM dbo.table 
    WHERE isdeleted = 0 AND isinedit = 0 
)
SELECT
  *
FROM GoodDataRows gp
  INNER JOIN GoodDataRows p ON p.parent_id = gp.id
  INNER JOIN GoodDataRows c on c.parent_id = p.id
```